# How to create a grid that will scale to the screen size and density

Tags: android, grid, size, screen

I want to create a simple grid of 6 square buttons in the center of the screen. To act as like a menu. The problem is that i don't know how i can scale these with the screen size. For example a 100dp square is ok on smaller screens but on larger screens it is dwarfed by the empty space. But making the squares bigger has the opposite effect on smaller screens.

Is there a easy way to do this or will i need to programmatically create the squares at runtime with a lot of maths.

I would give code but I don't really have anything that not a basic XML file that hard codes the sizes of the squares.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimensions (specially the ones measured in dp, such as the sides of a square button or the distance between buttons) can be dinamically defined in `dimens.xml`, which by its turn can be defined for different screen sizes by creating special folders such as `/res/values-hdpi`, `/res/values-xlarge`, `/res/values-sw720dp` etc. with their own `dimens.xml` files inside. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for further details.

In your xml layout you do:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/distance_between_buttons"
    android:src="/res/drawable/imgbutton"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/distance_between_buttons"
    android:src="/res/drawable/imgbutton"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
    android:src="/res/drawable/imgbutton"/>
```

In /res/values/dimens.xml you can have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_height">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_width">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="distance_between_buttons">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

In /res/values-large you can have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_height">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_width">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="distance_between_buttons">40dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: What would the dimens.xml hold? Could you perhaps give a quick code snippet?

Comment: So if I had a layout not in one of these special folders but the dimen.xml in these folders. When it inflates the layout it will read the dimen.xml that applies to the current screen size. Is that correct?

Comment: Don't forget the 's' in dimens.xml. Yes that is corret.

Comment: Thanks You. It was very helpful. I ticked this as correct answer.

Comment: As a last comment, it is more appropriate to create folders based on independent density than screen size, for reasons described in http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview.